# Контейнер vector

Tags: c++, vector, олимпиада

Петя успевает по математике лучше всех в классе, поэтому учитель задал ему сложное домашнее задание, в котором нужно в заданном наборе целых чисел найти сумму всех положительных элементов, затем найти где в заданной последовательности находятся максимальный и минимальный элемент и вычислить произведение чисел, расположенных в этой последовательности между ними. Так же известно, что минимальный и максимальный элемент встречаются в заданном множестве чисел только один раз и не являются соседними. Поскольку задач такого рода учитель дал Пете около ста, то Петя как сильный программист смог написать программу, которая по заданному набору чисел самостоятельно находит решение. Напишите рабочую программу.

**Входные данные**

В первой строке записано единственное число N (N≤15) — количество элементов массива. Вторая строка содержит N целых чисел, представляющих заданный массив. Все элементы массива разделены пробелом. Каждое из чисел во входном файле, в том числе и N, не превышает 20 по абсолютной величине.

**Выходные данные**

В единственную строку нужно вывести два числа, разделенных пробелом: сумму положительных элементов и произведение чисел, расположенных между минимальным и максимальным элементами. Значения суммы и произведения не превышают по модулю 10^6.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long n, s = 0, p = 1; // long long из-за 10^6
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> v(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> v[i];
// создал массив
    }
    int imn = 0, imx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (v[i] < v[imn]) {
            imn = i;
        }
        if (v[i] > v[imx]) {
            imx = i;
        }
// мин и мах есть
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) if (v[i] > 0) s += v[i];
    cout << s << " "; // сумма
    for (int i = imn + 1; i < imx; i++) p *= v[i];
    cout << p; // произведение
    return 0;
}
```

Мне пишет: "Программа выдает неверный ответ"

***Что мне нужно сделать в данном случае?***

Comment: https://pro-prof.com/forums/topic/acmp_hometask-stl

Comment: А почему вы решили, что минимальный элемент обязательно идет перед максимальным? Может ли быть наооборот?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша главная проблема - минимальное число может идти после максимального :)

Добавьте одну строчку:

```
cout << s << " "; // сумма

if (imn > imx) { int t = imn; imn = imx; imx = t; }  // ВОТ ЭТУ

for (int i = imn + 1; i < imx; i++) p *= v[i];
```